# highlight the text of the DOM range element,

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mozilla, gecko

I  am able to highlight the text on the HTML page(rendered through gtkmozembed), which is selected, like below.

```
    var range, sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt) {
          range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        }
        document.designMode = "on";
        if (range) {
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
        document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, colour);
        document.designMode = "off";
   }
```

Well,it works very fine.Now i am trying to store the information(startNode, startOffset,endNode, endOffset) about the highlighted text, and next time when i open the same page,highlight the same text.
    I am able to successfully store the info and retrieve them when the same page opens.
And i am trying to highlight the text using following code.

```
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
    range.setEnd(endNode, endOffset);

    document.designMode = "on";
    range.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, colour);
    document.designMode = "off";
```

But it is not working as i am expecting. Can anyone help me to achieve the required? Thanks...

Comment: duplicate of [highlight the text of the DOM range element,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582831/highlight-the-text-of-the-dom-range-element)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `execCommand` method is a method of the document, not the Range. Also, `hilitecolor` only works in Firefox, so you should fall back to using `backcolor` in WebKit and Opera.

**UPDATE**

Fixed in IE 9.

```
function makeEditableAndHighlight(colour) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var range = null;
    if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }
    document.designMode = "on";
    if (range) {
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
    // Use HiliteColor since some browsers apply BackColor to the whole block
    if (!document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, colour)) {
        document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
    document.designMode = "off";
}

function highlight(colour) {
    var range, sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        try {
            if (!document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour)) {
                makeEditableAndHighlight(colour);
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            makeEditableAndHighlight(colour)
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        // IE <= 8 case
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering... still it is not working... this code is working fine when i try to highlight the text which is currently selected.i.e when i create the range like this.  sel = window.getSelection();  range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
It highlights the text which falls into range() element. But if i create the range using setStart() and setEnd(), it is not working...even though execCommand is of document's, somehow i need to specify, it should highlight the text under the range element, right? how can i do that? thank you....

Comment: This method will only work if the range is selected, since the commands executed by `document.execCommand` are designed to work on the current selection. I think your best option is to temporarily select the range you want to highlight. I will update my answer.

Comment: Hi,thanks it works,with small modification. "document.designMode = "on";" This function should be called before calling,"sel.addRange(range);".
Thanks once again...

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html) page should give you all the details about highlighting via script. I haven't done it myself, so it's probably best you use the page's recommendations.