# How to change color with new tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In my HTML file I have to change color with new tag.It will be changed permanently.If it's possible to do.Now I am using below code:

```
function alertSelection()
{
      var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
      content = range.extractContents(),
      span = document.createElement('b');
      span.appendChild(content);

      var htmlContent = span.innerHTML;

      range.insertNode(span);
}
```

when i press refresh i will be get old one.how to create tag when selecting.

Comment: Have a look at these links: [**link1**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2756931/1577396) and [**link2**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3223682/1577396) and also its duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever  you want to change some style through then use `style`

element.style.css attribue = value

Example: `span.style.color = "green";`

Comment: Thank you very much.but i need this changes to be permanently.

Comment: permanent means.This will be in green until you change nect time

Comment: when i refresh the page it will be set to old one.but i need to store the updated file.

Comment: In my knowledge it is impossible to do that.When you refresh the page everything will go.But i dont know in html5 there is a concept of local storage.Is there any possibility with this

Comment: i  don't know html clearly i just started yesterday only.if its possible to access .txt file read and write.