# Inserting Custom Tags on User Selection

Tags: javascript

I want to insert my own custom tags and scripts around the selected text. Something like this

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var sel = window.getSelection();
range.setStart( sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset );
range.setEnd(sel.focusNode,sel.focusOffset);

highlightSpan = document.createElement("abbr");
highlightSpan.setAttribute("style","background-color: yellow;");
highlightSpan.setAttribute("onmouseout","javascript:HideContentFade(\"deleteHighlight\");");
highlightSpan.setAttribute("onmouseover","javascript:ShowHighlighter(\"deleteHighlight\",\""+id_val+"\");");  
highlightSpan.appendChild(range.extractContents()); 
range.insertNode(highlightSpan);
```

This works in normal scenarios but if I select some text in different paragraphs the extractContents API will validate the HTML returned and put additional tags to make it valid HTML. I want the exact HTML that was selected without the additional validating that javascript did.

Is there any way this can be done? 
I have tried it the way mentioned in [How can I highlight the text of the DOM Range object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582831/highlight-the-text-of-the-dom-range-element) but the thing is I want user specific highlights so if A has added some highlight B should not be able to see it. For this I have my backend code ready.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap with tags the selected text that belongs to different paragraphs, you create invalid HTML code.

This is an example of invalid HTML code that you would generate.

```
<p>notselected <span>selected</p><p>selected</span> notselected</p>
```

In order to accomplish your task, you need to wrap with tags each text in each paragraph of the selection resulting in a code like this.

```
<p>notselected <span>selected</span></p><p><span>selected</span> notselected</p>
```

To accomplish this you have to iterate over all nodes selected and wrap the selected text like this:

```
function wrapSelection() {
    var range, start, end, nodes, children;

    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    start = range.startContainer;
    end = range.endContainer;

    children = function (parent) {
        var child, nodes;

        nodes = [];
        child = parent.firstChild;

        while (child) {
            nodes.push(child);
            nodes = nodes.concat(children(child));
            child = child.nextSibling;
        }

        return nodes;
    }

    nodes = children(range.commonAncestorContainer);
    nodes = nodes.filter(function (node) {
        return node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
    });
    nodes = nodes.slice(nodes.indexOf(start) + 1, nodes.indexOf(end));
    nodes.forEach(function (node) {
        wrap = window.document.createElement("span");
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(wrap, node);
        wrap.appendChild(node);
    });

    start = new Range();
    start.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
    start.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startContainer.length);
    start.surroundContents(window.document.createElement("span"));

    end = new Range();
    end.setStart(range.endContainer, 0);
    end.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
    end.surroundContents(window.document.createElement("span"));
}
```