# How to get caret position within contenteditable div with html child elements?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, caret

I am working with a contenteditable div that will have the option to have inline html elements such as  tags in the text flow.

At certain points I need to grab the caret position but have found that with the example code the position returned is incorrect if the caret is after an html child element.

**I need a cross browser solution that will allow me to store the position of the caret so that it can be restored a split second later even with the presence of html elements in the text flow.**

Example:

```js
function getCaretPosition(editableDiv) {
    var caretPos = 0, containerEl = null, sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == editableDiv) {
                caretPos = range.endOffset;
            }
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        if (range.parentElement() == editableDiv) {
            var tempEl = document.createElement("span");
            editableDiv.insertBefore(tempEl, editableDiv.firstChild);
            var tempRange = range.duplicate();
            tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
            tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
            caretPos = tempRange.text.length;
        }
    }
    return caretPos;
}

$('div').keyup(function(){
   alert(getCaretPosition(this));
});
```

```css
div{width:300px; height:100px; border:solid 1px #DDD;}
div a{background:#333; color:#FFF;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable=true>
    some example text <a>anchor tag</a>&nbsp;
</div>
```

Original JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wPYMR/2/

Comment: What happens (or can happen) to the contents of the div during this split second?

Comment: The last word type can be removed and the caret position corrected.

Answer (score 4):

I've answered a very similar question here: [Editing Iframe Content in IE - problem in maintaining text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767037/editing-iframe-content-in-ie-problem-in-maintaining-text-selection/5770175#5770175)

Here's a slightly simplified version of that answer:

If you're not changing the contents of the contenteditable element then the following functions will do. Call `saveSelection()` before doing whatever you need to do and `restoreSelection()` afterwards. If you are changing the content, I'd suggest using my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library's [save/restore selection module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SelectionSaveRestoreModule).

```
var saveSelection, restoreSelection;
if (window.getSelection) {
    // IE 9 and non-IE
    saveSelection = function() {
        var sel = window.getSelection(), ranges = [];
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                ranges.push(sel.getRangeAt(i));
            }
        }
        return ranges;
    };

    restoreSelection = function(savedSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        for (var i = 0, len = savedSelection.length; i < len; ++i) {
            sel.addRange(savedSelection[i]);
        }
    };
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    // IE <= 8
    saveSelection = function() {
        var sel = document.selection;
        return (sel.type != "None") ? sel.createRange() : null;
    };

    restoreSelection = function(savedSelection) {
        if (savedSelection) {
            savedSelection.select();
        }
    };
}
```

Example use:

```
var sel = saveSelection();
// Do stuff here
restoreSelection(sel);
```

Comment: how could this be applied to a single contenteditable div? Will this wokr when the contenteditable element has child elements?

Comment: @TimDown how this answer could help to get a caret position ?

Answer (score 0):

```
        var display = $("#autocomplete");
        var editArea = $('#editArea');    
        console.log(e.target.selectionStart);           
        var pos = $("#editArea").caret();
        var offset = editArea.offset();
        // now you can use left, top(they are relative position)
        display.css({
            left: offset.left + 10,
            top:  offset.top + 13,
            color : "#449"
        })
        display.toggleClass("show");
        return false;
```