# Maintain cursor position in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, dom

First of all, this is similar to these:

[Editing Iframe Content in IE - problem in maintaining text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767037/editing-iframe-content-in-ie-problem-in-maintaining-text-selection/5770175#5770175)

[How to get caret position within contenteditable div with html child elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951886/how-to-get-caret-position-within-contenteditable-div-with-html-child-elements?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Basically, I'm writing something similar to the new tweet editor in twitter. Inside a `div` with `contentEditable` set on, I am parsing the text. When I detect what I think is a URL, I strip that text out and enter into an `<a>` tag inside the div (e.g. entered message of `go to www.google.com` becomes `Go to <a href='..'>www.google.com</a>`. BUT, the caret position is lost when I do that.

Using the suggestion by @Tim-Down in those other SO posts will only work as long as you don't edit the DOM (as he says). I AM editing the DOM, so the caret position is lost.

Is it possible (ideally without using the Rangy library referenced) to achieve this by working on the current code.

The code that I have at the moment (from the other SO posts):

```
var saveSelection, restoreSelection;
if (window.getSelection) {
    // IE 9 and non-IE
    saveSelection = function(win) {
        var sel = win.getSelection(), ranges = [];
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                ranges.push(sel.getRangeAt(i));
            }
        }
        return ranges;
    };

    restoreSelection = function(win, savedSelection) {
        var sel = win.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        for (var i = 0, len = savedSelection.length; i < len; ++i) {
            sel.addRange(savedSelection[i]);
        }
    };
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    // IE <= 8
    saveSelection = function(win) {
        var sel = win.document.selection;
        return (sel.type != "None") ? sel.createRange() : null;
    };

    restoreSelection = function(win, savedSelection) {
        if (savedSelection) {
            savedSelection.select();
        }
    };
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
$('div').on('keyup paste', function(e) {
    var ranges = saveSelection(window);
    var newContent = /* Get the new HTML content */;
    $('div').html(newContent);
    restoreSelection(window, ranges);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the text the user sees remains the same (which your question seems to imply is the case), you could use a character offset-based solution. I've posted some code for that elsewhere on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950376/96100

I also answered a related question quite recently:

[jQuery: Convert text URL to link as typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636218/jquery-convert-text-url-to-link-as-typing/14637351#14637351)

Comment: That's perfect (The first link did the job)

Comment: Just spotted a bug with this solution. All works but if you hit enter for a new line in the div, the cursor is set back on the previous line (presumably because of the divs that get entered).

Comment: @MattRoberts: Yes. There are limitations to this method, which is based only on text nodes and therefore doesn't take into account line breaks implied by `<br>` and block elements.

Comment: Perhaps if I detect a keyCode of 13 (enter key) then write some logic to go to the last position in the div...

Comment: @MattRoberts: I have written a fuller solution for my Rangy library (http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/textrange.html) but the code is enormous. I may try and come up with a compromise some day.

Comment: So if I use your rangy lib, would it solve all these issues? Would I need to use the saverestore module, the textrange module or both?

Comment: @MattRoberts: Just the TextRange module. It handles all the line break issues. There are `saveCharacterRanges()` and `restoreCharacterRanges()` methods of Rangy's selection object. Docs: https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/TextRangeModule

Comment: It seems to play well in FF, but not in chrome - added a simple jsfiddle for you : http://jsfiddle.net/mattwoberts/xjhsh/ - just try hitting return in chrome in that editable div.

Comment: @MattRoberts: Hmm, you're right. I thought it handled that case. I'll look into it.