# Filter words with color using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I found this code which `censors` the words in the filter,but instead of filtering I want it to have a different `background color` or a `different text color`(like red).

Whatever I have tried I have commented on jsfiddle.

This is the Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/xe2Zj/257/

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xe2Zj/258/

Since you want to mark specific words, the `<mark>` seems a good candidate for the job. You can style your `mark` as you want with CSS.

I just changed these two lines:

```
$('.post').text(function(i, txt){
```

to

```
$('.post').html(function(i, txt){
```

and this one from

```
var replacement = '*'.repeat(filter[i].length);
```

to

```
var replacement = '<mark>' + filter[i] + '</mark>';
```

---

**Edit**:
Another much [simpler solution](http://jsfiddle.net/xe2Zj/260/):

```
var filter = [' ass ', ' words '],
    reg = new RegExp("(" + filter.join("|") + ")", "g");

$(".post").html(
    $(".post").html().replace(reg, "<mark>$1</mark>")
);
```

Comment: wow thnx bro,could you tell how to change the text color,just incase?

Comment: thnx man..but cant i change the baackground from yellow to some other color,i think yellow is by default

Comment: @User211 Yes, yellow background is the default style for `mark`. In my previous comment I added another link with white background. BTW, check out my update with a much simpler solution

Comment: thnx again...i m new to jquery..also while typing also i can do it right instead of hardcoding it in p tag?using ur new method..

Comment: yes, in that case, I guess you will have to run that `replace` inside a `change` or `keyup` event.

Comment: `<input>` is an inline element, which means `html()` makes no sense. Also you cannot style individual characters in your input text. You need to output your text to another blocked element: [http://jsfiddle.net/xe2Zj/269/](http://jsfiddle.net/xe2Zj/269/)

Comment: thnx again..but i dont want to change the color of the text in the div,but instead change the color while typing itself...the project is like,i am typing and some words which r slang will get colored telling the user,this word is slang as he types(by the change of the color)..

Comment: You cannot style input text. Use a `contenteditable` div **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/xe2Zj/275/)** However there are problems with caret position, see [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194364/maintain-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-div)

Comment: so even instead of text if i use a ckeditor this wont be possible..right?

Comment: I never used ckeditor, but looks like it is possible. Give it a try

Comment: sorry to disturb u again,but instead of color,wat if i want to alert the word..how do i  change the code for that?

Comment: this shud have work http://jsfiddle.net/xe2Zj/300/  but  no idea y it isnt working

Comment: If you look at console, you will see why. You need `alert(reg.test($(this).val()));` instead. Maybe this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/wZ9NL/

Comment: wow thnx again...But wen i use alert and type a censored word it gives an alert but wen i type the nxt word or words it goes on throwing d alert...http://jsfiddle.net/xe2Zj/312/ 
looks lyk it takes d all the words into considerattion

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49210/discussion-between-jose-rui-santos-and-user211)

Answer (score 0):

> Use contains in Jquery. Select all elements that contain the
>   specified text.

```
var array = ["sample" , "hello"]

$.each(array , function( index, value ) {
      $( "div:contains("+value +")" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
});
```

Comment: There are no `div`s in the given example, and even if there was, this would mark the whole div as red, not just the words