# javascript - how to wrap text blocks in <span> containing html tags in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm unable to figure this out in Internet Explorer, but I want to be able to wrap a text block with  tags that contain various html tags in it.  I am writing a highlighting function where you highlight text with your mouse and the selection you highlight is wrapped in a `<span>` tag.  For example, consider the following text block (as input):

```
<p>Lorem <i><b>ipsum dolor</b> sit amet</i>, consectetur <b>adipiscing elit</b>. Morbi</p>
<p></p>
<p>mperdiet, augue id sagittis porta, leo leo...</p>
```

I want the output to be (if you were to highlight the entire thing):

```
<p><span class='id1 highlight'>Lorem </span><i><b><span class='id1 highlight'>ipsum dolor</span></b><span class='id1 highlight'> sit amet</span></i><span class='id1 highlight'>, consectetur </span><b><span class='id1 highlight'>adipiscing elit</span></b><span class='id1 highlight'>. Morbi</span></p>
<p></p>
<p><span class='id1 highlight'>mperdiet, augue id sagittis porta, leo leo...</span></p>
```

(and highlight could be something like: `.highlight{background-color:yellow}` for example)

I'm retrieving the string by using: `htmlStr = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;`

The best I can figure out so far is to use:

```
document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML( "<span class='id1 highlight'>" + htmlStr + "</span>" );
```

edit: I also want to assign another class to the highlight for tracking purposes (id1 in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky to achieve in the general case (think of selections crossing element boundaries: a single `<span>` cannot be used to surround such a selection). You can use `document.execCommand()` to do this in all major browsers. See my answer to a similar question here: [How can I highlight the text of the DOM Range object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582831/highlight-the-text-of-the-dom-range-element/2583895#2583895)

**UPDATE**

To wrap the whole selection in `<span>`s with a particular class, you could use the [CSS class applier module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule) of my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library. It works in all major browsers. However, each applier object only deals with one class, so you'll need to use two for your case. Example code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var highlightApplier, idApplier;

    window.onload = function() {
        rangy.init();
        highlightApplier = rangy.createCssClassApplier("highlight", true);
        idApplier = rangy.createCssClassApplier("id1", true);
    });

    function toggleHighlight() {
        highlightApplier.toggleSelection();
        idApplier.toggleSelection();
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Toggle highlight"
    onclick="toggleHighlight();">
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion, however I need to be able to attach an "id" to the highlights for tracking purposes.  FYI-I'm using class instead of id because I need the same "id" across all the highlights.  I know it's possible to do this because there is open-source javascript code out there that lets you do it (wrap text blocks with span tags) in Firefox/Chrome/Safari.  However, that code does not work in IE.  Does the execCommand allow you to add <span> tags around the entire highlight at least?

Comment: @James: `execCommand()`'s precise behaviour varies between browsers. What's the open source code you had in mind?

Comment: THANK YOU!! This is a REALLY awesome library!  I wish I knew about this sooner!!