# javascript: how to reverse a range.execCommand method

Tags: javascript, selection, highlight, execcommand

If I use the execCommand method to highlight the selected text:

```
document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, colour);
```

as it is suggested [in this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582831/highlight-the-text-of-the-dom-range-element), and then I want to come back and cancel the highlight format (that is, to return to the situation as it was before I highlighted some text), what could I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will remove formatting:

```
document.execCommand("RemoveFormat", false, null);
```