# Removing <span> tag while leaving content intact, with just javascript

Tags: javascript, highlighting

I'm doing some in page highlighting, and found the most popular example when using text selection and adding spans is by switching to designMode and running execCommand

[How can I highlight the text of the DOM Range object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582831/highlight-the-text-of-the-dom-range-element)

There's no follow up though on how to remove the span tags once created.
I saw some examples using jquery and the replaceWith, but none with straight javascript.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do something like:

```
// Where span is a reference to the span to be replaced
var text = span.textContent || span.innerText;
var node = document.createTextNode(text);
span.parentNode.replaceChild(node, span);
```

Comment: this answer and xavi's works well, though can it be amended to work with links if the <span> contains a links or images inside it. Probably cause its creating a textnode but using innerHTML in replace inputs links in their full <a>....</a> format.

Comment: If the selection includes markup that you want to keep, then use innerHTML. However, you should not be wrapping arbitrary markup in span elements as only a limited set of other elements may appear as child nodes of span elements. Also, the selection may start inside one element and end inside another, you can't simply wrap that in a span.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new text node with the contents (`innerHTML`) of the `<span>`. Replace the `<span>` node with `replaceChild` on its parent:

`spanTag.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(spanTag.innerHTML), spanTag)`

Comment: Don't use innerHTML, use textContent or innerText as appropriate.

Comment: @RobG Could you please explain why?

Comment: Because innerHTML will return any internal HTML also, whereas the textContent and innerText properties only return text. If the content is supposed to be only text, then the most appropriate property to use is the one that only returns text.