# Getting the next character after window.getSelection()

Tags: javascript, getselection

Is there anyway to get the next character after a window.getSelection()?  I need to check if the character after the selected text is a space or not...

EDIT:  Thank you for your answers!  I'm basically using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582831/how-can-i-highlight-the-text-of-the-dom-range-object)  to highlight text, but would like to limit things to full words.  I've used the presented solution below (by Steven) as a starting point; I *think* that the following should work:

```
sel = window.getSelection();
var text = sel.anchorNode.nodeValue;
var index = sel.baseOffset + sel.focusOffset-1;
var isSpace = text[index] === undefined;
if (isSpace) {
alert("space");
}
```

(In the link above, I used this code right after the makeEditableAndHighlight function call).

Comment: Thanks!  And....my solution above doesn't actually work.  :(

Answer (score 2):

This is a start, provided there is at least one more character in focusNode:

```
window.getSelection().focusNode.textContent.charAt(window.getSelection().focusOffset)
```

Comment: I need to do some more testing, but this is looking promising!

Comment: This is working for me on Safari.  But, after doing some research, I've found that the getSelection() method doesn't work for older browsers.  I wonder if I can somehow use Tim Down's rangy...

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
var sel = window.getSelection()
var text = sel.anchorNode.nodeValue;
var index = sel.baseOffset + sel.focusOffset;
var isSpace = text[index] === ' ';
```

Comment: This is not a correct example because the selection string representation might occur multiple times in the `anchorNode`

Comment: Better as `var index = window.getSelection().baseOffset + window.getSelection().focusOffset;`

Comment: Also, no need for index + 1 this way.

Comment: On the right track, still not working in all the cases (i am testing on you code snipper above + Developer Tools in Chrome, selecting `sel =`)

Comment: The problem is much much more complicated depending where the selection was started (`anchor`) and where it ends (`focus`). Think about selecting forward or backward the text …