# How to get the element(s) created when text is highlighted with document.execCommand

Tags: javascript, range, highlight, execcommand

How can I retrieve the element that is created to wrap text with a highlighted background when using `document.execCommand('BackColor', false, color)` (or `'HiliteColor'`)? For reference, I'm using Tim Down's solution to highlight selected text: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2583895/494954.

I know I could get a node in the selection, and go up the chain until I found an element that has the background color that I specified, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution?

Comment: Which browsers do you care about?

Comment: Oh, hey it's you! :) IE9+ and latest-ish versions of modern browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really an elegant solution. You can use [DOM mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) for now in IE >= 9 and non-IE browsers but there's a good chance these events will be removed in future in favour of [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Here's a demo that uses the `DOMNodeInserted` event. It only detects the elements that have been inserted and doesn't filter out any that aren't highlighting elements:

http://jsbin.com/joqofojetu/1/

It would be possible to implement a similar solution with mutation observers, with two disadvantages: first, IE only supports them from version 11 onwards. Second, unlike mutation events, mutation observers are not guaranteed to fire synchronously so you'd have to wait a while before processing the elements you've collected.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a bit of a hack, but at least it's a little cleaner than my original solution. Thanks!