# Prevent text selection on double click in a React component

Tags: reactjs, ondoubleclick

I have a react component that displays some text inside a div. I also have a double click handler on the div. Everything works fine except the text is shown as selected when the user double clicks on it. This is to be expected, but I want to prevent this happening.

I tried to use event.preventDefault() but it made no difference. Any ideas?

```
var Example = React.createClass({
    toggle: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div onDoubleClick={this.toggle}>
                Example text!
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the CSS, attributes, and select event handler as in this question:

[How to disable text selection using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700000/how-to-disable-text-selection-using-jquery)

which should be doable just in the JSX. If that fails, you might try adding a componentDidUpdate handler, get the DOM node, and manipulate the selection range (see [How can I highlight the text of the DOM Range object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582831/how-can-i-highlight-the-text-of-the-dom-range-object))

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `userSelect: 'none'` -

```
<div onDoubleClick={this.toggle} style={{userSelect: 'none'}}>
    Example text!
</div>
```