# getSelection & surroundContents across multiple tags

Tags: javascript, getselection

I've got a script that changes the background colour of text that has been selected. However i'm encountering an issue when the text is selected across multiple elements/tags.

The code that i've got is:

```
var text = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var colour = document.createElement("hlight");
colour.style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
text.surroundContents(colour);
```

And the error being output is:

```
Error: The boundary-points of a range does not meet specific requirements. =
NS_ERROR_DOM_RANGE_BAD_BOUNDARYPOINTS_ERR
Line: 7
```

I believe this is to do with the getRange() function though i'm not too sure how to proceed since I am a beginner at javascript.

Is there any other way I can replicate what I am trying to achieve?

Many thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582831/highlight-the-text-of-the-dom-range-element and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622629/javascript-highlight-selected-range-button

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This question has been asked today: [How can I highlight the text of the DOM Range object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582831/highlight-the-text-of-the-dom-range-element)

Here's my answer:

The following should do what you want. In non-IE browsers it turns on designMode, applies a background colour and then switches designMode off again.

**UPDATE**

Fixed to work in IE 9.

```
function makeEditableAndHighlight(colour) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }
    document.designMode = "on";
    if (range) {
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
    // Use HiliteColor since some browsers apply BackColor to the whole block
    if (!document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, colour)) {
        document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
    document.designMode = "off";
}

function highlight(colour) {
    var range, sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        try {
            if (!document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour)) {
                makeEditableAndHighlight(colour);
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            makeEditableAndHighlight(colour)
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        // IE <= 8 case
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Tim, that worked perfectly and apologies for the duplication. The other thread didnt come up in my searches.

Comment: but how do you call the function *highlight* ?

Comment: @LayaleMatta: Example: `highlight("#ff0000")` will add a red background to the currently selected text.

Comment: @TimDown can you please share a fiddle for the code above.

Answer (score 2):

Well I think the use of [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) library is great in this case. The library's intention is to highlight all instances of a certain word in the HTML document, but it can be tweaked through the **filter** option function, and additional span attributes can be added through the **each** option function.

```
function markFunc(node, text, color) {
  var instance = new Mark(node);
    instance.mark(text, {
    "element": "span",
      "className": color,
      "acrossElements": true,
      "separateWordSearch": false,
      "accuracy": "partially",
      "diacritics": true,
      "ignoreJoiners": true,
    "each": function(element) {
            element.setAttribute("id", "sohayb");
            element.setAttribute("title", "sohayb_title");
       },
    "done":function(totalMarks) {
            window.getSelection().empty();//This only in Chrome
            console.log("total marks: " + totalMarks);
     },
      "filter": function(node, term, totalCounter, counter) {
        var res = false;
        if (counter == 0) {
            res = selectionRange.isPointInRange(node, selectionRange.startOffset);
        } else {
        res = selectionRange.isPointInRange(node, 1);
        }
        console.log("Counter: " + counter + ", startOffset: " + selectionRange.startOffset);
        return res;
        }
  });
};
```

Check this [JSFiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/sohaybh/3LhL3jok/) for completed code that highlights user's selection, even across multiple HTML elements.