# how to set carret after element

Tags: javascript

How i can set cursor position after `<b>some test</b>`

Example code:

`<div contenteditable="true"><p><b>some test</b></p></div>`

I'm using setStartAfter & setEndAfter, but not working

Comment: Huh? Elements in the DOM don't have caret positions. Do you mean 'How do I set the caret position after some text in a textarea?'

Comment: Is the parent a [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_Editable) element?

Comment: Do you mean the cursor or the insertion point? A caret is a character (downward-pointing arrow).

Comment: I mean cursor position
( contentEditable - yep)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-caretcursor-position-in-contenteditable-element-div