# How can I retain `contenteditable` focus() events in a Meteor template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have a `<div contenteditable class="content"> </div>` in my template whose inner HTML is tied to Mongo. When I (dynamically) add a new `.content`, I'd like to be able to focus it so that the next thing a user types is entered in the contenteditable div.

However, the `.focus()` event doesn't play nicely with Meteor's rerendering; even SO's [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-caretcursor-position-in-contenteditable-element-div) don't work: The JS executes without error, but the focus event doesn't seem to trigger anything (or, it *does* but it's immediately overwritten by Meteor's rendering).

My question is: How can I force focus that `div`? A plan I considered was setting a tabindex and then artificially tabbing to that element, but I'm hoping to not have to resort to such silliness.

[EDIT] I'm aware of the `{{#constant}}` tag, but as far as I can tell, that stops the element from being rerendered at all, which is certainly not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place focus code into Template.blah.rendered.

Comment: Took me a moment to realize that `this` isn't the `this` I was necessarily expecting... But a single line of jquery later, this is far more functional than I was even hoping. Thank you!

Comment: @j6m8 will you please post a working example of this? We are looking for a similar solution.