# How to place span tags around each word in div with contenteditable set

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

So my current predicament is that I can not place html `<span>` tags around each word in the content editable div. With the span tags having a sequential div id. 
The html code I have is below.

```
<div contentEditable id="InputOne" onkeyup="UpdateTextarea(event)"></div>
```

and here is the JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Alert;
var A=0;
var B=0;
var C=0;
var Alert;
var Text2= [];
var OldStorage= [];
var OutputText= [];
    function UpdateTextarea(e)
    {
Alert = document.getElementById('InputOne');
Alert = Alert.innerText || Alert.textContent;
 //Alert = Alert.split("\n\n").join("<br>");
TextTest=Alert.split("\n\n");
Text1=Alert.split("\n\n");
B=0;
C=0;
for (index = 0; index < Text1.length; ++index) {
Text1[index]="<p> "+Text1[index]+" </p> ";
/*if(C===0){
Text1[index]="<p>"+Text1[index];
C=1;
}else{Text1[index]=Text1[index]+"</p>";C=0;}*/

B++;
}
Text1=Text1.join("");
//Text1="<p>"+Text1+"</p>";
Text2 = Text1.split(" ");

A=0;
for (index = 0; index < Text2.length; ++index) {
if(Text2[index] !== "<p>" && Text2[index] !== "</p>")
    {
    //alert(Text2[index]);
   OutputText[index]="<span id='Word-"+A+"'>"+Text2[index]+" </span>";
    if(Text2[index] !== OldStorage[index])
    {

//Getjson dont bother
var getJSON = function(url, successHandler) {
  var xhr = typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined'
    ? new XMLHttpRequest()
    : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  xhr.open('get', url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var data;
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) { // `DONE`

        data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        successHandler && successHandler(data);

    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};
//end
getJSON("//codeonthecloud.com/School/Science-Fair/Backend.php?Q="+Text2[index]+"&Id="+index, function(Data) {
  document.getElementById("TESTDIV").innerHTML = "<a href='" + Data.A1 + "'>" + Data.A2 + "</a>";

});

        OldStorage[index]=Text2[index];
    }
}else{OutputText[index]=Text2[index];}
A++;
}
DivA=OutputText.join("");
document.getElementById("InputOne").innerHTML=DivA;

    }


</script>
```

But the problem I have having with the JavaScript is
1. it should not rewrite every time because that is resource intensive and can cause lag.
2. Because .innerhtml is replacing the content the cursor is moving backwards so when you type the text comes out in reverse.
So I guess what I really want is a way to find spaces in the div with the id `InputOne` and place closing and opening span tags with the id set to a sequential number. If you are wondering why I need this it is so that the words can be uniquely identifiable so that I can set font sizes on a word by word basis.
NOTE: I would prefer to not use jquery

Answer (score 1):

Following seems to work for me

#### EDIT

The function that I added in, the setCaretLast(), is not mine. I found it [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6249440/2825551). As soon as I can, I'll update the answer again to use regex so that it doesn't have to change the contents ALL the time.

```js
var something = document.getElementById('something'); // Gets the div, I couldn't remember what yours was called.
something.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
   if(event.keyCode==32) {
    
     event.target.innerHTML = wrap_words(this.innerText);
     setCaretLast(this.id);
     console.log(this.innerHTML);
    }
   
  }); //Adds a key down event to gather the key presses. I have it set to run the 
//wrap_words function after the user hits enter. You should be able to set it however 
//you like. Perhaps just have this function called (minus the event.keycode stuff) on blur instead?

function wrap_words(text){
  var split_text = text.split(' '); //Splits the text by string
  var _out = []; //The output array
  count = split_text.length; //Gets the count. I was originally going to use this for somethign else but got side tracked. 
  for(var i=0;i < count; i++){
      _out[i] = "<span id=\"word-"+i+"\">"+split_text[i]+"</span>"; //I would normally say "use element nodes" but this was just way, way faster.
    }
  
  return _out.join(' '); //Combines the _out array by spaces.
}


//Not my function.
function setCaretLast(el) {
    var el = document.getElementById(el);
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(el.childNodes[el.childNodes.length-1], 1);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    el.focus();
}
```

```html
<div id="something" contenteditable>
   you can type here
  </div>
```

Comment: So i tried the code but it still does have the problem of moving the carrot around and i want it on space bar press so it would be key code "32". but thank you for your time so far and your effort towards my problem

Comment: Why do you want it on spacebar press, exactly?

Comment: I am making a form input field for my website where when you press space bar it will use JavaScript to get the contents for each word separately. But can you please do one more thing for me I would like the  div id="something" to be able to separate paragraphs I tried to add text = text.split("\n\n").join("<br>"); but it will still move the text I think it is because of the set carrot position function? Thank you for the help so far and I will be marking this as the accepted answer because it answered the initial question

Comment: I had been working on a solution, and I've come to the conclusion it's a bit of a pain. The problem is that contentEditable is meant for WYSIWYG editors, and there's some differences in how things are parsed between browsers. The problem, then, is trimming unnecessary HTML while keeping necessary formatting. It begets some problems.

Comment: well can you at least tell me how to place tags around paragraphs and also allow paragraphs i define a paragraph as two "\n" tags (line breaks) and would like them to also be in div tags named differently with sequential numbers.

Comment: In regards to the formatting of paragraph tags, what have you tried?