# Get a word in textarea on mouse over

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, textarea, jquery-events

I have a `<textarea>` HTML element. My goal is when mouse is over a word in the textarea I need to get the word and do something with it. How can it be implemented? What event should I use?

Comment: you need to get like **tooltip** on mouse over

Comment: Just and idea. I would use ContentEditable div. Parse it's value by spaces, wrap the words into spans and put it back. And then bind hover event for that spans. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943803/how-to-place-span-tags-around-each-word-in-div-with-contenteditable-set

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the mouseover and mouseenter events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104344/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mouseover-and-mouseenter-events)

Answer (score 4):

As per my knowledge, you can't do that.

Only way you can do this, wrap each with element like `<span>` and add on mouse hover event to all `<span>` element.

```
<div class="spanhover"><span>Wrap</span><span>all</span><span>elements</span></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.spanhover span').bind('mouseenter', function () {
    alert($(this).html() + " is your word");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I thought about this. But I need something where I can edit text. I can make the div to be editable (contenteditable). But how to support text-to-span converting when the text is changed? It seems like there is too many edge cases