# Caret position in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've spent quite some time trying and searching but could not find a IE11 compatible version of this legacy code:

```
setCaretPosition: function (len, iCaretPos) {
    var oSel = top.document.selection.createRange();
    oSel.moveEnd('character', -len);
    oSel.moveStart('character', iCaretPos);
    oSel.moveEnd('character', 0);
    oSel.select();
},
```

It's actually just setting the caret position. I've read that `document.selection` is no longer supported in IE11 and that `document.getSelection()` was the alternative. I've also seen [this](http://help.dottoro.com/ljrvjsfe.php) great resource. However, I could not manage to get the `moveEnd` or `moveStart` methods working with `document.getSelection()`.

Does anybody know a working IE11 equivalent?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-caretcursor-position-in-contenteditable-element-div?

Comment: Can you please share the rest of the rendered markup?