# How to set caret position in contenteditable span and then sendKeys?

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

```
<span name="workitemContent" contenteditable="">root 0 child 0 zzzz</span>
```

For instance, how could I use protractor to set my cursor after the word "child" and then send additional text (with sendKeys or similar) into the span at that position?

Afterwards it might look like:

```
<span name="workitemContent" contenteditable="">root 0 child with red hair 0 zzzz</span>
```

I've seen other questions that answer how to do this with JavaScript (such as [How to set caret(cursor) position in contenteditable element (div)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-caretcursor-position-in-contenteditable-element-div)), but not with protractor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perform a *click on the element with an offset*, e.g.:

```
var elm = element(by.name("workitemContent"));
browser.actions().mouseMove(elm, 5, 0).click().perform();
```

But, I'm not sure whether you can call it a reliable approach.

---

Another option would be to follow the solution provided in the question you've linked and execute javascript via `browser.executeScript()`:

```
var elm = element(by.name("workitemContent"));

function setCursor(arguments) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(arguments[0].childNodes[2], arguments[1]);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}
browser.executeScript(setCursor, elm.getWebElement(), 5);
```