# Summernote - On focus, insert cursor at the end of editor

Tags: javascript, cursor-position, summernote

When the Summernote text editor initializes with the `focus` property set to `true`, the editor gains focus but places the cursor at the beginning of the editor.

My preference would be to have the cursor placed where the user had clicked initially.  At a bare minimum I would just need to place the cursor at the end of the editor.

The Summernote API doesn't seem to directly support this and I've tried various *hacky looking* solutions;  Such as emptying the text area, creating the editor, then inserting the HTML nodes.  The cursor remains at the beginning of the line still.

Forgot to include my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/madChemist/gvy3po4L/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution I've modified to work for me:

```js
$.fn.extend({
    placeCursorAtEnd: function() {
        // Places the cursor at the end of a contenteditable container (should also work for textarea / input)
        if (this.length === 0) {
            throw new Error("Cannot manipulate an element if there is no element!");
        }
        var el = this[0];
        var range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var childLength = el.childNodes.length;
        if (childLength > 0) {
            var lastNode = el.childNodes[childLength - 1];
            var lastNodeChildren = lastNode.childNodes.length;
            range.setStart(lastNode, lastNodeChildren);
            range.collapse(true);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

Which originally came from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6249440/2921200 and then I modified to work with jQuery & specifically against Summernote.

Comment: This code should be called after jQuery has been initialized.
EX: $('#FieldToFocus').placeCursorAtEnd();

Comment: I tried doing that in my [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39396888/4896260) and I wasn't able to get it working. Can you help me @Mad-Chemist on where it should be placed?

Comment: @usr4896260 Check out my response to your ticket here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39706123/2921200

Comment: @Mad-Chemist, where I need to add this code also how can I call that function?

Comment: Add the above code within jQuery's $(document).ready callback if possible.  You want the above code to execute as soon as jQuery is initialized.  Once that happens, you are free to call the method at your leisure "$('#FieldToFocus').placeCursorAtEnd();" but swap out the jQuery selector in the example.

Comment: The answer is missing what element to call this on: `$("#your-summernote-element").closest(".note-editing-area").find('[contenteditable]').placeCursorAtEnd();`