# Is there any solution to identify <a> tag range to appear the cursor just after the end of all <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you please check https://jsfiddle.net/s7fxy8jp/8/

Is there any solution to identify  tag range so that when I click on "Set Focus To Element Z" from the fiddle, the cursor will appear just after the end of all  tag.

HTML

```
<div tabindex="-1" id="scripted"><a>Element A (script-only focusable)</a><a>Element B (script-only focusable)</a></div><div id="test">Set Focus To Element Z</div>
```

CSS

```
div:focus {
background-color: Aqua;}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('test').onclick = function () {
document.getElementById('scripted').focus();};
```

Comment: It means what ? : 'the cursor will appear just after the end of all tag.'

Comment: The cursor needs to be appear just after the end of all <a> tag in the div (having id="scripted")

Comment: So it means you want to move cursor at the end of that tag right?

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

For the cursor to appear, I believe the `div` must be `contentEditable`. You could change the attribute onClick to only make it editable after the script activates it.

Once editable you can [set the selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6249440/650881) to place the cursor position.

```
function cursorToEnd(el) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    // Note positioning after the last child works for your
    // example but might not be the most robust option depending
    // on your expected div contents.
    range.setStartAfter(el.lastChild);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}

document.getElementById('test').onclick = function () {
    var e = document.getElementById('scripted');
    e.contentEditable = true;
    cursorToEnd(e);
};
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8z6q5gs1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is this, but you won't be able to see cursor at the end because i am not converting that div into text box.

```js
document.getElementById('test').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('scripted').focus();
   placeCaretAtEnd( document.getElementById("scripted") );
};

function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
            && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}
```

```css
div:focus {
  background-color: Aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div tabindex="-1" id="scripted"><a>Element A (script-only focusable)</a><a>Element B (script-only focusable)</a></div>
<div id="test">Set Focus To Element Z</div>
```