# Chrome Android Angular Contenteditable validating input before modification

Tags: android, angular, google-chrome, contenteditable

I have a `Angular 4.3` application where i have a `contenteditable`

I need to validate input before it can be it can be reflected in UI (in this instance only numbers upto three charecters can be typed )

In desktop browsers this accomplished using `(keydown)` event and returning `false` on invalid input

But in mobile browser(Android Chrome) both `keydown` and `keypress` events are not triggered consistently, instead [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) Event is fired.

but using [`InputEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent) i cannot prevent modifying data on invalid input

Example HTML template

```
<p contenteditable=true (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)" (input)="onInput($event)"></p>
```

and component code is

```
public onKeyDown($event:KeyboardEvent){ // works
    if(invalidInput){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public onInput($event:InputEvent){ // does'nt works
    if(invalidInput){
        $event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**PS:** Is there a way to trigger numberpad  keyboard for input with contenteditable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work with `input`.

**HTML:**

```
...
<div #myEditable contentEditable (input)="valueChanged($event.target.innerText)"></div>
...
```

**TypeScript:**

```
.....
if(value.length>20){ //for example
   this.name = this.name.slice(0,20);
   this.validationError=true;
   this.myEditable.nativeElement.innerText = this.name;
....
```

It's not very neat I think to keep that last part in the component, so you can maybe move to a directive.

**[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqs8we)**

Comment: Thanks for answer, I want to avoid this solution as cursor can be at any point, then doing validation will be a mess after modifification

Comment: What do you think of this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41034697/5468463

Comment: Do you have any constraint to use contenteditable? Because with <p> and and <input> it would be easier. If you are interested, I could post a snippet

Comment: thanks again , I think i will go with this logic only, along with https://stackoverflow.com/a/41034697/5468463 

Solution will be complex but will work i think