# Caret position resets in contenteditable when setting innerHTML

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, caret

I'm trying to create a container field component, I'm using the html attribute `contenteditable`, but when I replace the `innerHTML` value of my component the cursor(caret) puts it back to position 0. is there a way to keep the cursor position?

Its look like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found real the solution in another topic:
[How to set caret(cursor) position in contenteditable element (div)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-caretcursor-position-in-contenteditable-element-div)

Here is the code:

```
function createRange(node, chars, range) {
    if (!range) {
        range = document.createRange()
        range.selectNode(node);
        range.setStart(node, 0);
    }

    if (chars.count === 0) {
        range.setEnd(node, chars.count);
    } else if (node && chars.count >0) {
        if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            if (node.textContent.length < chars.count) {
                chars.count -= node.textContent.length;
            } else {
                 range.setEnd(node, chars.count);
                 chars.count = 0;
            }
        } else {
            for (var lp = 0; lp < node.childNodes.length; lp++) {
                range = createRange(node.childNodes[lp], chars, range);

                if (chars.count === 0) {
                   break;
                }
            }
        }
   }

   return range;
};

function setCurrentCursorPosition(element,chars) {
    if (chars >= 0) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();

        range = createRange(element.parentNode, { count: chars });

        if (range) {
            range.collapse(false);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
    }
};

function isChildOf(node, parentId) {
    while (node !== null) {
        if (node.id === parentId) {
            return true;
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }

    return false;
};

function getCurrentCursorPosition(parentId) {
    var selection = window.getSelection(),
        charCount = -1,
        node;

    if (selection.focusNode) {
        if (isChildOf(selection.focusNode, parentId)) {
            node = selection.focusNode;
            charCount = selection.focusOffset;

            while (node) {
                if (node.id === parentId) {
                    break;
                }

                if (node.previousSibling) {
                    node = node.previousSibling;
                    charCount += node.textContent.length;
                } else {
                     node = node.parentNode;
                     if (node === null) {
                         break;
                     }
                }
           }
      }
   }

    return charCount;
};
```

Comment: In my case it always returns -1;