# Move text to beginning on focusout when contentEditable overflows

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/qpysmb9t/

Whenever text in the `contentEditable` element becomes bigger that the `max-width` of the div(try typing some long text), than the left part gets hidden and what's on the right is shown. This is okay while you type, but on focus out I'd like to reverse this and show text from the beginning.

How can I achieve this?

```
<div tabindex="-1" contenteditable="true" class="name-data">This is test</div>

.name-data{
  max-width:180px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

UPDATE: The solution suggested is to move the caret position. This example illustrates this:

https://jsfiddle.net/qpysmb9t/1/

Unfortunately, just moving the caret does not reposition text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set caret(cursor) position in contenteditable element (div)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-caretcursor-position-in-contenteditable-element-div)

Comment: I've added another example that illustrates that suggested answer does not solve my problem