# How to stop cursor from automatically moving in contentEditable div element

Tags: javascript, html

I know there are solutions for this problem, but I am unable to understand them or get them to work for me.

I tried copying [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58564024/is-there-a-simple-way-to-prevent-the-cursor-from-moving-in-a-div-contenteditable). From my understanding, `const offset = sel.getRangeAt(0).startOffset` gets the cursor's position, `nRange.setStart(el.childNodes[0], offset)` and `nRange.collapse(true)` set nRange to start at the cursor's original position and collapse towards that point. Then `sel.addRange(nRange)` is used to move the cursor to the end.

The above strategy does not seem to work for me. On the key-press, the cursor still goes to the start position of the div's text. On subsequent presses, I get the error `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': There is no child at offset 10.` I am not entirely sure about why this error occurred, [but when looking at the Watches in my debugger, I note that the offset does exceed the size of my div element's NodeList](https://imgur.com/a/iiBv0c6)

Below is the code that gave me the above output. What changes do I have to make to stop the cursor from moving?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id = "thisDiv" contenteditable = "true" style="border: 5px solid black"></div>

        <script>
            window.onload = (event)=> {
            window.addEventListener("keydown", updateText);
            }

            function updateText(event){
                const el = document.getElementById("thisDiv");
                const sel = window.getSelection();
                const offset = sel.getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
                if(event.keyCode == "13" || event.keyCode == "32"){
                    el.innerHTML += `<span>Added text </span>`;
                }
                const nRange = document.createRange();
                nRange.setStart(el.childNodes[0], offset);
                nRange.collapse(true);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(nRange);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```