# How to restore caret position in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve that when the user presses the reset button, the cursor positions back to the beginning of the input.

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this?

[image]

```js
function restore(){
    // here need to set the position
};
```

```css
p {
  text-align:left;
  padding:10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  border:1px black solid;
}

button{
 font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable="true"></p>

<button onclick="restore()">Restore</button>
```

Comment: Is this what you are asking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-keyboard-caret-position-in-html-textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Range` and `Selection` objects as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6249440/3930247):

```js
function restore() {
  var el = document.getElementById("editable");
  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  range.setStart(el, 0);
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

```css
p {
  text-align:left;
  padding:10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  border:1px black solid;
}

button{
 font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<p id="editable" contenteditable="true"></p>

<button onclick="restore()">Restore</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the Input tag instead of the P tag, this code is appropriate :

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = document.getElementById("myInput");
  text.select();
  text.setSelectionRange(text.value.length, text.value.length)
}
```

```css
button{
 font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="hello" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```