# Editable text inside span tags & place cursor at the end (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I want a feature where clicking the Edit button will make the text content inside span tags editable. I was able to do that but couldn't figure out how to get the blinking cursor at the end of text.

Below is the simplified version of my code.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  const span=document.querySelector('span');
  span.setAttribute('contentEditable', 'true');
  span.focus();
  let val=span.innerText;
  span.innerText='';
  span.innerText=val
})
```

```html
<span>this is the span tag</span> <button>Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new `range` object set the node you wish to set the range selection to `addRange` using `getSelection`... See notes in code snippit

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNodeContents

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/removeAllRanges

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const span = document.querySelector('span');
  span.setAttribute('contentEditable', 'true');
  span.focus();
  let val = span.innerHtml;
  span.innerHtml = '';
  span.innerHtml = val;
  
  //set a new range object
  let caret = document.createRange();
  //return the text selected or that will be appended to eventually
  let sel = window.getSelection();
  
  //get the node you wish to set range to
  caret.selectNodeContents(span);
  //set collapse to null or false to set at end of node
  caret.collapse(null);
  //make sure all ranges are removed from the selection object
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  //set all ranges to null and append it to the new range object
  sel.addRange(caret);
})
```

```html
<span>this is the span tag</span> <button>Edit</button>
```

*This post may also be helpful to you...

[How to set caret(cursor) position in contenteditable element (div)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-caretcursor-position-in-contenteditable-element-div/39161623#39161623)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, if my answer works for you feel free to check it as an accepted answer. Happy coding ;)