# How to set the cursor position in a contenteditable div in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, contenteditable

I'm trying to create a text editor and I'm using a `contenteditable` div and everytime someone changes the text inside it I want to wrrap all that new text with a `strong` element and change the div's innerHTML

This is what I tried  (I'm using react/nextjs)

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!divRef.current) return;

    let text = divRef.current.innerText;
    const htmlArray = text.split(" ").map((word) => {
      return `<strong style="color: red">${word} </strong>`;
    });
    text = htmlArray.join("");
    divRef.current.innerHTML = text;
  }, [text]);
```

everything here works as expected but everytime I type a character the cursor goes to the start and the text is rendered backwards. How can I fix the issue I want the cursor to stay an the end of the div when user type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the caret (cursor) position in a contenteditable element (div)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-the-caret-cursor-position-in-a-contenteditable-element-div)

Comment: @JanPfeifer I have tried that method but it is not working for me (throwing error)

`execute 'setStart' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that you're updating the innerHTML of the contenteditable div every time `text` changes.

You need to capture the actual position, and set it back after state change with [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Selection)

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!divRef.current) return;

  // Get the current cursor position
  let selection = window.getSelection();
  if (!selection.rangeCount) return;
  let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  let cursorPosition = range.startOffset;

  // Update the innerHTML
  let text = divRef.current.innerText;
  const htmlArray = text.split(" ").map((word) => {
    return `<strong data-id="hey" style="color: red">${word} </strong>`;
  });
  text = htmlArray.join("");
  divRef.current.innerHTML = text;

  // Get the new cursor position
  selection = window.getSelection();
  range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

  // Set the cursor position to the new position
  range.setStart(range.startContainer, cursorPosition);
  range.collapse(true);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}, [text]);
```

Comment: it's throwing this error 

`Failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 0 is not a valid index.`

Comment: Ha, it means you have to add a condition to check if there is range. I updated the code

Comment: the error is gone but the issue is still there, the cursor goes back to the start