# Need to be able to add a text to arbitrary location in a div tag as a marker

Tags: javascript, range

I have a div tag in my page that could have an arbitrary amount of child nodes. But there is a certain length at which i need to slice it and only show the sliced text. This is the code i have:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv")
var range = document.body.createTextRange();
range.moveToElementText(myDiv);
range.move("character",150);
range.text = "!!!";
var html = myDiv.innerHTML;
html = html.slice(0,html.indexOf("!!!"));//+"...";
myDiv.innerHTML = html;
```

I am doing it this way so that i can conserve the html on the value of the div and at the same time i can make sure that i am not slicing in between a tag. This works fine in IE but obviously dosent so in firefox. Can anybody help me with giving me a equivalent code for firefox.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to extract the HTML for the first 150 characters of a `<div>`. It's based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240139/highlight-text-range-using-javascript/6242538#6242538) and the same caveats about the naivete of the implementation apply.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrEme/2/

Code:

```
function getTextNodesIn(node) {
    var textNodes = [];
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        textNodes.push(node);
    } else {
        var children = node.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; ++i) {
            textNodes.push.apply(textNodes, getTextNodesIn(children[i]));
        }
    }
    return textNodes;
}

function copyCharacterRange(srcEl, destEl, start, end) {
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(srcEl);
        var textNodes = getTextNodesIn(srcEl);
        var foundStart = false;
        var charCount = 0, endCharCount;

        for (var i = 0, textNode; textNode = textNodes[i++]; ) {
            endCharCount = charCount + textNode.length;
            if (!foundStart && start >= charCount
                    && (start < endCharCount ||
                    (start == endCharCount && i < textNodes.length))) {
                range.setStart(textNode, start - charCount);
                foundStart = true;
            }
            if (foundStart && end <= endCharCount) {
                range.setEnd(textNode, end - charCount);
                break;
            }
            charCount = endCharCount;
        }

        destEl.appendChild(range.cloneContents());
        range.detach();
    } else if (document.selection && document.body.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(srcEl);
        textRange.collapse(true);
        textRange.moveEnd("character", end);
        textRange.moveStart("character", start);

        destEl.innerHTML = textRange.htmlText;
    }
}

var srcEl = document.getElementById("src");
var destEl = document.getElementById("dest");

copyCharacterRange(srcEl, destEl, 0, 150);
```