# WYSIWIG JavaScript HTML editor with API and advanced text processing support (like word detection)

Tags: javascript, html, api, wysiwyg, text-processing

I`m looking for WYSYWIG JavaScript HTML editor for my app. I`ve already tried some of them, for example from [**this**](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors) list but some are too complex and some are missing basic features...

Requirements:

- It should work with newest stable release of: Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer (and also Apple Safari support would be nice).
- It should have basic features like bold, italic, color change, headers, paragraphs, no-formatting, aligns - those are basic options that browser may handle (it is how it`s done in most WYSIWIG editors).
- I don`t need any UI - so if it comes with UI - I should be able to easily remove it. I mean I don`t need any buttons, color pickers, image insert dialogs etc. - I will build my-own menus
- Instead of UI I need complex API where I can for example extract selected/full text/HTML, insert text/HTML, replace text/HTML.
- I need advanced text processing support - this is what I`m looking for and cannot find anywhere - **I need to detect what word is under cursor**. For example we have "This is sample text" and User clicks on "sample" - I need to know it`s position, text and HTML.
  I found something like this: [Javascript Rich Text Editor with get AND set cursor position support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131830/javascript-rich-text-editor-with-get-and-set-cursor-position-support) - but it`s not full answer for this problem.
- It would be great if it`s easy to embed (not to much files), lightweight and fast.
- It should be licensed by opensource/GPL/or some other open/free license.

If I miss any info - please let me know and I`ll update them.

Maybe some of You know some nice libraries? Or maybe there are other nice solutions to achieve my goals?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're looking for a WYSIWYG editor, but don't need any UI? You do realize that WYSIWYG stands for *what you see is what you get*, right? A pure UI interface that abstracts away the programming know-how....

Comment: @Roddy - yes, yes, I meant I don\`t need any buttons, color pickers, image insert dialogs etc - I only need API to build my-own menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a WYSIWYG editor as such, but my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library may help you build a simple editor. In particular, the new [TextRange module](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/textrange.html) provides methods that work with words.

Comment: This is really great. I think I may start with it if I won\`t find any better solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try nicedit. http://nicedit.com/index.php

Comment: It does not meet my requirements. It doesn\`t have any text processing API. No advanced getting/setting/replacing of HTML/text methods etc. It is too simple in my case.