# JQuery Find and change style of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to write a function that will search all the content in my HTML page for a specific string, and if it finds it then change the color of the text.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do that :

CSS :

```
.someclass {
    color: red;
}
```

Javascript :

```
$('p:contains('+yourstring+')', document.body).each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(
        new RegExp(yourstring, 'g'), '<span class=someclass>'+yourstring+'</span>'
  ));
}​);​
```

Note that this would make problems if yourstring is in a tag or an attribute.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/G7jm3/)

Be careful to run this code before you attach handlers to your paragraphs (or the elements inside which could contain yourstring, for example links).

Comment: Won't this wrap the entire div containing the string, not just the string itself?

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm not sure of what you mean. I've added a demo

Comment: I was wrong... However, the drawback of this approach is that it overwrites the HTML, so if you have any handlers on the nodes that get replaced, you've removed them. Ideally, you would find the text range and make a node out of it.

Comment: Yes. I've changed it to target the P element. This avoids other problems too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with dystroy's answer is that it will overwrite the entire HTML, so if you have any handlers within a node containing your text, they will be removed.

The correct solution is to use [text ranges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/range) to update only the text itself, not all of the HTML around it. See [Highlight text range using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240139/highlight-text-range-using-javascript)

And for fun, there is a built-in method [window.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.find) that works in [FF and Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/tZZeN/). It's not in the standard though and will only find one at a time. Just like ctrl+f.

```
window.find("anything");
```

Answer (score 0):

> **JQuery Find and change style of a string >> Only Copy Paste and run :)**

```
  $('#seabutton').click(function()
        {
            var sea=$('#search').val();
            var cont=$('p').val();
            alert(cont);
            $('p:contains('+sea+')').each(function()
                 {
    /*          $(this).html($(this).html().replace(new RegExp(sea, 'g'),'<span class=someclass>'+sea+'</span>'));
     */            $(this).html($(this).html().replace(
                        new RegExp(sea, 'i'), '<span class=someclass>'+sea+'</span>'
                  )); 
            });

        });
        $('p').click(function()
        {
            $(".someclass").css("color", "black");
        });
        $('#search').blur(function()
        {
            $(".someclass").css("color", "black");

        });

    })


    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .someclass {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Select Country:<select id="country" name="country">
    </select>
    <table id="state" border="1">


    </table> -->
    <br>
    Enter Text:<input type="text" id="search"/><input type="button" id="seabutton" value="Search"/>
    <div id="serach">
    <p>This is ankush Dapke
    </p>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```