# html Part of variable change fontsize and font background

Tags: html, css, regex

**Hello!**

I have an autogenerated text which is always changing but always contains a "Q+4 digits number".

```
<style>
                .metarrovid {
                  color: #000000;
                  position: absolute;
                  z-index: 8;
                  display: block;
                  font-weight: bold;
                  left: -1250px;
                  top: 315px;
                  font-family: arial;
                  font-size: 30px;
                  max-width: 700px;
                }
</style>
<?php

    $text=file_get_contents('http://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/observations/metar/stations/LHBP.TXT');
    $metar = $text;
    $metarrovid = substr($metar,16,10000);
    echo '<div class="metarrovid">', "MET REPORT" .$metarrovid,'</div>';
?>
```

**It looks like this:**

[image]

My question is how can I do that (in this example:"Q1017") be bigger and have yellow background like this:

**I want it to look like this (just illustration):**

[image]

Comment: You can parse this text using JS and find required string or patter (use regex). After this, you can add some styles to this part, or better, wrap into the <span> element with css class, that have your styles. Those solutions are not elegant, but should work. Implementation of this solution you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780784/jquery-find-and-change-style-of-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can use javascript make it!

```
<script>    
window.onload = function() { 
    var domText = document.querySelector("body").innerHTML; 
    document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = domText.replace(/(.)(Q\d{4})(.)/, "$1<span style='font-size:24px;color:red;'>$2</span>$3") 
}
</script>
```

You must select the dom witch you want to change. document.querySelector("body") while replace all the text in body tag.