# Set maximum text selection range in webpage

Tags: select, text, copy, range, max

I would like to set limit of text selection on my web page with javascript.
What I mean - 
if someone try to select text with the mouse cursor (or pressing ctrl+a), the maximum selected range have to be 100 characters, i.e. he will copy maximum 100 characters from my page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could detect selection change events (IE and WebKit support a [`selectionchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event on `document` and you could use a variety of other key and mouse-related events in other browsers) and use a [character-based approach to modify the selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6242538/96100) but I would consider very carefully before doing this: it breaks standard selection behaviour the user expects and I can't really imagine a situation where it would be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.onselectionchange = zzz;

function zzz()
{
var selectedRange = returnSelection();

    if(selectedRange.length>50)
    {
    //alert('opaaaa');
    deselectSelection();
    }

}

function returnSelection()
{
    if (window.getSelection)
        {
        if (window.getSelection().toString().length > 0)
        {
        return window.getSelection().toString();
        }
    }
    else if (document.getSelection)
    {
        if (document.getSelection().toString().length > 0)
        {   
        return document.getSelection().toString();
        }
    }
        else if (document.selection)
    {
        if (document.selection.createRange().text.toString().length > 0)
        {       
        return document.selection.createRange().text.toString();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function deselectSelection()
{       
    if (window.getSelection) 
    {
        if (window.getSelection().empty) // Chrome
        {  
        window.getSelection().empty();
        } 
        else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) // Firefox
        { 
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        }
    } 
        else if (document.selection) // IE?
    {  
    document.selection.empty();
    }
}
</script>

  <p>
  A web page could be considered as a document tree that can contain any number of     branches. There are rules as to what items each branch can contain (and these are detailed     in each element’s reference in the “Contains” and “Contained by” sections). To understand     the concept of a document tree, it’s useful to consider a simple web page with typical     content features alongside its tree view, as shown in
  </p>
  </body>
</html>
```