# Select a portion of text within a HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, selection

I would like to create a function that select a given text inside a HTML element.

For example calling `selectText('world')` would select `world` in a markup like `<span>Hello </span><strong>world</strong>!`

Lots of answers on similar questions suggests to use `range` and `selection` but none of them work in my case (some would select all the text, some won't work with such markup, ...).

For now this is what I have **(it doesn't work)**:

```
function selectText ( element, textToSelect ) {
    var text  = element.textContent, 
        start = text.indexOf( textToSelect ),
        end   = start + textToSelect.length - 1,
        selection, range;

    element.focus();

    if( window.getSelection && document.createRange ) {
        range = document.createRange();

        range.setStart( element.firstChild, start );
        range.setEnd( element.lastChild, end );

        selection = window.getSelection();

        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange( range );
    } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();

        range.moveToElementText( element );
        range.moveStart( 'character', start );
        range.collapse( true );
        range.moveEnd( 'character', end );
        range.select();
    }
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle so you see what is actually happening: http://jsfiddle.net/H2H2p/

Outputed error :

```
Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': The offset 11 is larger than or equal to the node's length (5).
```

P.S.: no jQuery please :)

Comment: Here's how you select the text, **http://jsfiddle.net/H2H2p/1/**, it's `setStart(node, offset)`, and you're getting the offset from the text only, so it's 11, but the textnode you're targeting doesn't have 11 characters, so you end up with an error.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H2H2p/2/

Comment: @adeneo Thank you, I feel much closer to my goal :) Do you see a way to make it work if I want to select `Hello wo` in `<span>Hello </span><strong>world</strong>!` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of your approach of finding the text within the element's `textContent` and [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6242538/96100).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H2H2p/3/

Code:

```
function selectText(element, textToSelect) {
    var elementText;
    if (typeof element.textContent == "string" && document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        elementText = element.textContent;
    } else if (document.selection && document.body.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElement(element);
        elementText = textRange.text;
    }

    var startIndex = elementText.indexOf(textToSelect);
    setSelectionRange(element, startIndex, startIndex + textToSelect.length);
}

function getTextNodesIn(node) {
    var textNodes = [];
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        textNodes.push(node);
    } else {
        var children = node.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; ++i) {
            textNodes.push.apply(textNodes, getTextNodesIn(children[i]));
        }
    }
    return textNodes;
}

function setSelectionRange(el, start, end) {
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        var textNodes = getTextNodesIn(el);
        var foundStart = false;
        var charCount = 0, endCharCount;

        for (var i = 0, textNode; textNode = textNodes[i++]; ) {
            endCharCount = charCount + textNode.length;
            if (!foundStart && start >= charCount
                    && (start < endCharCount ||
                    (start == endCharCount && i < textNodes.length))) {
                range.setStart(textNode, start - charCount);
                foundStart = true;
            }
            if (foundStart && end <= endCharCount) {
                range.setEnd(textNode, end - charCount);
                break;
            }
            charCount = endCharCount;
        }

        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (document.selection && document.body.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(true);
        textRange.moveEnd("character", end);
        textRange.moveStart("character", start);
        textRange.select();
    }
}
```