# Highlight html from javascript : document.evaluate returns null node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xpath

In my index.html there's a div that will be filled with some html content returned from an ajax request to another web page. I need to highlight some specific part of the loaded html content that is determined by xpath. Using the code in the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996357/highliting-text-in-html-page-having-only-xpath-anchoroffset-and-focusoffset) it's returning a null node. Obviously when i try to use an xpath that is referred to the code from the ajax request as shown:

```
var node = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
```

it returns a null node.

I'm searching for something useful for replace "document" inside the function with the purpose of obtain a not null node referred to the code from ajax and not from the index.html that still contains the empty div.

The div i need to fill is this: 'div id="mainAreaContent"
  /div' and here you can find what i want to insert (https://ideone.com/bseVSF), the path i'm using is `/table/tr/td/table[1]/tr/td[2]/h3[2]/text()`.
The `document` variable is the index.html that calls the js script.

Comment: Can you please post your HTML?

Comment: Also post your XPath expression. And, does the `document` variable refer to the content returned from the Ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> ```
> /table/tr/td/table[1]/tr/td[2]/h3[2]/text().
> ```

If I open your file in oXygen (an XML editor with XPath/XSLT etc support), and I make it valid (your referenced file is incomplete/broken), then your given XPath selects the text node `"The Architecture and Datasets of Docear's  Research Paper Recommender System"` ([sic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic)).

You wrote:

> The div i need to fill is this: 'div id="mainAreaContent" /div

I don't see any `div` in your XPath, nor anything with an id `mainAreaContent` in your source HTML, so if you are searching for that, it is correct that you get `null`: it isn't there.

#### About your XPath expression

The XPath you showed starts at the root. If your root is not `<table>`, but `<html>` for instance, you should change it to include the path up to your `table` element. The (incomplete) document you showed started at `<table>`, but I assume it is part of an HTML page. Perhaps your select expression should start like `/html/body/div/p/table...`, but I don't know, your didn't show that part.