# Programmatically select text between two points in a textarea

Tags: javascript

I want to programmatically select a snippet of text in a textarea between two points, for example from character 50 to 58.

I've tried `textarea.setSelectionRange(50, 58)` but doesn't work

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240139/highlight-text-range-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your text area to be:

```
<textarea id="myTextArea">Some initial text</textarea>
```

you need to set focus first.

```
let textarea = document.getElementById("myTextArea");
textarea.focus();
textarea.setSelectionRange(50, 58);
```

Comment: can you please share some code that you're using. HTML as well as JS