# Range.select() equivalent method for non IE browsers

Tags: javascript, range, contenteditable

If I have

```
var range = document.body.createTextRange();
```

and I call `range.select();` in Internet Explorer, what's the equivalent of the range select method in other browsers(Firefox, Chrome, Opera)? I am looking for something that makes my caret visible inside a contenteditable div after having created the range object and added it to the current selection.

Thanks!

Later edit:
I need this because I am trying to make my application run on all browsers and I need to position the caret inside a contenteditable div just after the text selected from a pop-up by the user. So far my application is working on IE, but I need to also make it work on Opera, Firefox and Chrome. My Javascript code for placing the caret on IE looks like this:

```
 function setCaretPos()
 {
    if (document.selection) 
    {
       /* IE */
       var range = document.body.createTextRange();
       range.moveToElementText(editableDiv);
       var insertedSpan = document.getElementById('span' + count);
       var preCaretRange = document.body.createTextRange();
       preCaretRange.moveToElementText(insertedSpan);
       preCaretRange.moveEnd("character", 2);
       range.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", preCaretRange);
       range.collapse(false);
       range.select();
    }
    else
    {
     if (window.getSelection) {
     /* Firefox, Opera, Chrome */
     var sel = window.getSelection();
     if(sel.rangeCount)
     {
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        var insertedSpan = document.getElementById('span' + count);
        range.selectNodeContents(insertedSpan);
        range.collapse(false);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
       }
     }
 }
```

Using the code above, the text inside the span gets selected, but my problem is that the caret is not showing up after the inserted span, it simply disappers.

Any suggestions much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could check out [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/). It may be what you're looking for.

Comment: You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2584352/2039657 "this") question, I think it does what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent in other browsers is via the [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection) object:

```
var range = document.createRange();
var selection = window.getSelection();
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

Comment: Hi, Tim! Thanks for your answer. In fact let me tell you why I need this: I need to position the caret after some text selected by the user. I have tried var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                var insertedSpan = document.getElementById('span' + count);
                range.selectNodeContents(insertedSpan);var selection = window.getSelection();
                selection.removeAllRanges();
                selection.addRange(range); but my caret is not showing up at all the inserted span. How can I make it visible using the selection object?

Comment: @Crista23: You may need to call the `focus()` method of your contenteditable element.

Comment: One more question though: is there a way I can move my caret 2 characters away from the inserted span? (I mean something equivalent to the line preCaretRange.moveEnd("character", 2); ) in the rest of the browsers? I need it so that the user gets an empty space added automatically after his selection so that he can keep on writing. Thanks.