# removeAllRanges slow in chrome / Alternatives?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, range, selection

I'm developping a markdown editor with node-webkit (Chromium 38.0.2125.104) that convert the markdown to html while typing, and render it in the same contenteditable (kind of highlighting). So everything works fine this way : i save the caret position by inserting a new node in the dom. Then i process my text. Then i get back the caret position and delete my marker node.

My problem is that i try to do all this as fast as i can. But more than half of the process time is taken by a single opération :

```
selection.removeAllRanges();
```

After having done everything and just before adding my created range to the selection object.
Around 15/20 ms lost into one operation, something that starts to feel when typing fast. Is there any way i could speed it up, like calling something else, or work a different way with the selection/ranges ?
thank you (i mean it, i always used this site for answers, but this is my first question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only interested in Chrome, you could try using the non-standard WebKit method `setBaseAndExtent()` (sorry, no documentation link because as far as I can tell it's never been documented) to set the selection directly. I have no idea if it will be any faster; I can't see why it would be.

Assuming your range is stored in a variable called `range` and your selection in `sel`:

```
sel.setBaseAndExtent(range.startContainer, range.startOffset,
                     range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! When removeAllRanges was getting slower and slower with more dom element in the page (sometime getting over 114ms) your solution takes 8ms in every situation !

Comment: I add that i used this solution in conjunction with some throttling to get a smoother experience for the user

Comment: I am having performance issues with this as well. I am using your highlighting method http://stackoverflow.com/a/2584352/494954 and I've tried replacing `removeAllRanges` and `addRange` with `setBaseAndExtent`, but it's still very slow (on the order of 2 *seconds*). My DOM is fairly heavy (think 1000+ positioned span elements). Any idea how I could improve perf? It looks like `execCommand` is also taking a fair bit of time (~1 sec). Thoughts?

Comment: Actually, I found that the problem was making the entire document editable. I instead make the `commonAncestorNode` editable in `makeEditableAndHighlight`, which is *significantly* faster.

Comment: @lakenen: That's a good idea. I think I first suggested making the whole document editable way back before all browsers had `contenteditable`. In your solution, you'll need to make sure `commonAncestorContainer` is an element rather than a text node before making it editable.

Comment: @TimDown yeah, I noticed that. I just ended up doing `commonAncestorContainer.parentNode` to be safe.

Comment: Here is a bug report https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138439 for addRange(). It seems that setBaseAndExtent() works same slowly for me