# Highlight the selected text in editable div using JS

Tags: javascript, html, select, highlight

I am not able to figure out, how to highlight a selected text in an editable div (when it contains many tags (nested) in it).

If I could get the exact position from where selection starts (index in the editable div, innerHTML), I could add a font tag over there with background color style (giving the effect of highlight). But I am not able to figure out a reliable way to get the index from where the selection starts.

My sample code is at: [Sample](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=db49c8cb57fa5ccd&id=DB49C8CB57FA5CCD!166437&ithint=file,html&authkey=!AMdi43XREGoGAHo).

"window.getSelection();" method gives me complete text of what has been selected, including nested tags (if I use innerHTML on it). Thus all I need is a reliable way to calculate the start index from where selection is starting.

Any help/reference is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
Suppose my oDiv has content:
<br><br><h2>I am H2, Title</h2>

And say I select H2 above, I need starting index as: 19 (counting all the tags inside oDiv). How can I get that? I need it to work for arbitrary deep nesting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select all DIV text with single mouse click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173194/select-all-div-text-with-single-mouse-click)

Comment: Thanks Dylan, but I am not able to figure out the connection. In the link you mentioned current element is added to the range (and element ID is being passed as function). In my case, I want to know exactly from which position the selection started and use that to insert a background color tag to highlight.

Comment: It is dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584301/getselection-surroundcontents-across-multiple-tags


I got it working (at least in chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var r = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);` - gives the range inside the selection.

`r.startOffset`, `r.endOffset` - gives you the bounds of the range in selection.

If the div you are interested in has a id then you can get the element by:

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("divId");
var r = document.createRange();
r.selectNodeContents(objDiv);
```

If the element doesn't have an id, then there are other means to get the object. See here: [Finding HTML Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp)

And now you can get the bounds of range `r` using the `startOffset` and `endOffset` properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need the index wrt the editable div. have edited my questions.

Comment: Tried and r.startOffset  it always gives 0, r.endOffset also return fixed value depending on the Div contents (irrespective of what i select). I guess  it is giving no of elements in the div