# Apply span to selected text in javascript

Tags: javascript, text, selection, selected

I would to apply a span class to selected text on browser window in Javascript (like an highlight feature).

I've tried with

```
function replaceSelectedTextWithHTMLString(newstring) {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();
    range.innerHTML = newstring;
}
```

but it does not work. If i try to insert as newstring= "< span = "myspan" > text < / span >" I can't look anything and the 'text' does not appear. Seems it does not like the HTML code. How can I solve it?

Comment: @Andy: That question was confusing: the OP seemed to want textarea-based solutions initially, so it hasn't had answers that would apply to this question.

Comment: @Tim: oh yeah, I see that now.  Hopefully the close vote will go ignored by people who read more carefully than me...

Answer (score 1):

How easy this is depends on what exactly you need to achieve. If all you need is basic highlighting using a background colour, your best bet is `document.execCommand()`. See the following for code to do this: [Change CSS of selected text using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223682/change-css-of-selected-text-using-javascript/3224513#3224513)

If you need to apply more styling than `document.execCommand()` can provide (there are also [various other formatting commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands) for things like bold and italic, but the markup this produces varies between browsers and isn't always CSS based), it's much trickier: in general, you need to surround every text node within the selection in a span with the desired class. I would suggest using [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) and its [CSS class applier module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule) to do this in a cross-browser way. Disclaimer: this is a plug for my own library.