# selection position of selected text of div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

I need to get the **position** of the selected text within a content non-editable div (not a textarea, not a rtf editor, just a simple div)

I want to do this in order to enable users to select pieces of an article and "highlight it", by wrapping it in a span with a different background and, of course, an article is build with divs and/or p-s etc, not textareas or rtfs

Any ideas?

P.s. You can also use jQuery :D

P.s.s. I need the **position** of the selection, not the selection itself. Aka: it start from index I to index J. I need this because the normal method of finding the text in the parent does not always return a unique result, which would suck :)

Comment: well if it were for jquery then it would have been a lot easier

Comment: Index I and J relative to what?

Comment: The number of characters in the div I assume.

Comment: @tak3r: Even if you get numbers representing character indices of the selection within a div, this won't help you if the selection crosses multiple paragraphs, or starts and ends within different elements, because then wrapping a single `<span>` around the selected text won't be possible. This is why I suggested `document.execCommand()`, which will take care of that for you.

Comment: yes, but just how cross-browsered is execCommand()?

Comment: @tak3r: Supported in all the major browsers for several years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to change the background of the selected text, the easiest way to do this is by using `document.execCommand()`. See my answer here: [Change CSS of selected text using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223682/change-css-of-selected-text-using-javascript/3224513#3224513)

Comment: Tim's answer is clean and fast. But if you want to do some interactions with the highlighted ranges, without breaking the original text flow and mess up the dom tree, I would suggest calculating the absolute layouts of each selected line, and add an overlay inline-block.  [See my answer here for details and examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43577515/290239).

Answer (score 2):

```
//Wrap selected text in span tags with the class 'hl'
//Take some action after (in this case, a simple alert)
$("p").live("mouseup",
    function() {
        selection = getSelectedText(); 
        if(selection.length >= 3) {
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace(selection, $('<\/span>').attr({'class':'hl'}).html(selection).parent().html()) );
            alert(selection);
        }       
    }
); 

//Grab selected text
function getSelectedText(){ 
    if(window.getSelection){ 
        return window.getSelection().toString(); 
    } 
    else if(document.getSelection){ 
        return document.getSelection(); 
    } 
    else if(document.selection){ 

        return document.selection.createRange().text; 
    } 
}
```

Code comes from here: http://esbueno.noahstokes.com/post/92274686/highlight-selected-text-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can check if text is selected by running :

```
window.getSelection and document.getSelection() and  document.selection
```

(because browsers can check this i different ways)
and then search for div containing this text .

Answer (score 0):

For getting the position of the selection, try these links:

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/153164-return-selectionstart-div

[Set cursor position on contentEditable <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div)

Answer (score 0):

Well, even though you found a solution to the problem stated in your 2nd paragraph, i don't think the answer to your main question has been given. :)

The object [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) has a property named [anchorOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/anchorOffset), giving exactly what you asked for (the position of the selected text within an element).  The above link will tell you about which browsers support it, i'm afraid IE <9 might not.

```
function show_selected()
{
    var sel = selection();
    console.log(sel.anchorOffset + ':' + sel);
}
```

Now if you bind `show_selected` to, say, `mouseup`, you will see the offset and the selected text printed on the js console.

The fonction `selection` may be the following, supposed to be cross-browser:

```
function selection()
{
    var sel;
    if(window.getSelection){
      sel = window.getSelection()
    }
    else if(document.getSelection){
      sel = document.getSelection()
    }
    else if(document.selection){
      sel = document.selection.createRange()
    }
    return sel
}
```