# How to change user's selection range in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, selection, range

The following JavaScript code can change user's selection range in UIWevView but iOS selection remains unchanged. How can I synchronize both selections, so when the app changes selection using JavaScript, iOS selection changes as well. Is it possible?

```
var sel = window.getSelection();

var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(sel.anchorNode,sel.anchorOffset + 1); // it removes the first letter from a selected range
range.setEnd(sel.focusNode,sel.focusOffset);

sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `Selection` object as you can in any other browser but iOS does not update the visible selection unless the selection is already visible, for reasons unknown to me. There's no way round this as far as I know.

Comment: If it's not possible, maybe I will try to highlight selection using css... not the best solution but better than nothing to make a new selection visible.

Comment: @user828845: `document.execCommand()` will do that for you. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3224513/96100

Comment: Thanks! I will try. By the way, I tried ::selection (css) to highlight selected text but unfortunately it doesn't work in Mobile Safari :(

Comment: Setting contentEditable to true allows for more robust text selection.