# With window.getSelection, how do I know affect text from two different nodes?

Tags: javascript

I have this code with which I put selected text inside a span that gives it a background-color with CSS.
When I try to 'mark' text from two different divs, or text which is inside any two tags, I get an error:
`Uncaught Error: BAD_BOUNDARYPOINTS_ERR: DOM Range Exception 1`

This is my code:

```
function highlightSelection()   {
var selection;



//Get the selected stuff
    if(window.getSelection) 
        selection = window.getSelection();
    else if(typeof document.selection!="undefined")
        selection = document.selection;

    //Get a the selected content, in a range object
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

    //If the range spans some text, and inside a tag, set its css class.
    if(range && !selection.isCollapsed)
    {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.className = 'highlight-green';
            range.surroundContents(span);
    }
}
```

The highlightSelection() is called with `onmouseup` event.
Thanks ahead!

Comment: If you simply want to know if the range is valid for surroundContents, then you can use try/catch.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve... are you simply trying to insert the selected text into a span tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `surroundContents()` method of Range only works when the contents of the Range can be surrounded within a single node. It's fairly intuitive with examples. So, where curly braces denote range boundaries, the following are OK:

```
One {two} three
One {two <b>three</b> four} five
```

... while the following are not OK:

```
One {two <b>three} four</b> five
One <b>two {three</b> <i>four} five</i>
```

Insetad, I suggest using `document.execCommand()` for applying a background colour to the selection, as this will deal with all this stuff for you. I've provided [code to do this on Stack Overflow before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224513/96100).

If you need to apply a class instead, you could use the [CSS class applier](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule) module of my [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy) library.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Iv'e now tried applying your code (I just found that SO discussion, I take the blame for insufficient research) but nothing happens.
Iv'e created a JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9gXWt/), could we continue this over chat? Thanks!