# updating the range in html

Tags: javascript, html, range

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change CSS of selected text using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223682/change-css-of-selected-text-using-javascript)

Highlighting text spanning many elements

```
if (window.getSelection) {
    userSelection = window.getSelection();
    if (userSelection.getRangeAt) {
        var range = userSelection.getRangeAt(0);
    } else {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(userSelection.anchorNode, userSelection.anchorOffset);
        range.setEnd(userSelection.focusNode, userSelection.focusOffset);
    }
}

var newNode = document.createElement("span");
newNode.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:yellow');

range.surroundContents(newNode);
```

This is working for the case of text within the same tag like

[image: in same tag]

Since span is inline block element which surrounds the selected text but I am not able to find any working solution for the case which includes other tags also in selected text like..

[image]

I am trying to do it for safari browser in ipad.

Do I need to parse the DOM element but I think it would consist of several cases.

Comment: Yes it is the similar question but it is not working in safari browser of ipad.

Comment: It definitely does work in iPad. http://jsbin.com/ayivap/3/

Comment: i am trying in safari browser of ipad simulator but its not working but its working great in desktop safari browser of mac.

Comment: I don't have the simulator available but it's working on my iPhone and iPad (both running iOS 5).

Comment: @ Tim Down: Still i find it difficult to be happening in ipad safari browser. I tried it but didn't get the result in ipad.