# underline text in contetnteditable using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to do a chrome extension that underlines specific words.
Assume the user writes "hello" then I want to underline it. 
The thing that in Facebook and other social media the text field is a content editable div.

How can I access that text and manipulate only specific words inside it? 
I have tried doing this, but it didn't work

```
$('body').on('focus', '[contenteditable]', function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    $this.data('before', $this.html());
}).on('blur keyup paste input', '[contenteditable]', function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('before') !== $this.html()) {
        $this.data('before', $this.html());
        $this.trigger('change');

    if ($this.text().includes("hello")){

        //document.execCommand('undeline'); //didn't work 
        //$this.style.textDecorationColor="red"; // neither did this
        //$this.style.textDecorationStyle="wavy";
    }
    }
});
```

Note: I have tried `document.execCommand` but it didn't give any results

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223682/change-css-of-selected-text-using-javascript) it might help you with the styling

Answer (score 0):

My pure JS solution:

```
    function logSelection(event) {
      const selection = window.getSelection().toString();
      const log = document.getElementById('log');
      console.log(selection, event); // debug

      // colors must be in hexadicemal (no #)
      const color = 'ff0000';
      const backColor = '0000ff';

      // apply css if you want
      this.style.textDecorationStyle="wavy";
      this.style.textDecorationColor='#'+color;

      document.execCommand('underline');
      document.execCommand('BackColor', false, '#' + backColor);
      document.execCommand('foreColor', false, color);
      //document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, '#' + color); not working

      log.textContent = `You selected: ${selection}`;
    }

    const content = document.querySelector('div[contenteditable]');
    content.addEventListener('click', logSelection);
```

also you can take a look into the [document.execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) docs